# How do I scan an item and what happens when I do?

Tags: starbound

I click on the scanner in my ship but I have no idea how to use it. How do I put an item in the scanner and what happens when I hit scan?

Obviously there are the "scanned items are destroyed" warnings at the top. But once I scan an item what can I do with it. Since it's a "printer" I'm assuming I can scan something to make more of it.

Is there a limit to what I'm allowed to scan/print, or a limit to how many times something scanned can be printed? Has anyone experimented with the printer yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put an item into the scanner and press scan. If nothing happens, the item cannot be scanned (or it is not coded yet since it is a beta).

If the item can be scanned, it will be destroyed and be made available for 3D printing which does cost pixels to perform. Pixels can be obtained by finding them in containers, by killing enemies, or by refining ores when you can build the Refinery.

Items that are known to work so far are various kind of seeds, like Grain or Banana Seeds.

Answer (score 2):

In stable 1.0 version of the game, scanning is one of the many functions of your Matter Manipulator.

[image]

To activate scan mode, use the shortcut (default: <kbd>N</kbd> key) or scoll your mouse wheel until the scan mode is highlighted on your hotbar. As part of the tutorial you are required to scan all the shops on the Outpost.

[image]

When in scan mode, scannable items near your pointer are highlighted. Items that have not been scanned before are shaded blue, and will turn orange when they have been scanned. Green items are items that need to be scanned to progress in quests. Only one instance of each item need to be scanned. Scanning does not destroy the item.

After scanning them item, your character will give a brief description of it in his or her own terms. Each race describe objects differently. Some items (mostly furnitures) are made available for printing at the Pixel Printer after scanning.